# Regex Match Words That End With Whitespace or Coma

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex that turns words preceeded by hashtags into links. Here:

```
public static string LinkifyHashTags(string text)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(text, "(\\#\\w+) ", "<a href=\"#\">$1 </a>");
    }
```

However, if the string is like this:

**"This turns #hashtags such as #Google+, #Twitter and #Youtube, into links"**

The only hashtags that will be matched are the **#hashtags** and **#Twitter**. *#Google+* and *#Youtube* are not matched. Any help with the code above?

Comment: Remove the space in the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the space, or using a lookahead assertion,  allow space, comma, plus sign, end of string to signify the end of hash tag.
You should look up what consitutes valid characters in a hash tag

```
 "(\\#\\w+)(?=[ ,+]|$)"
```

with optional many plus sign's as part of hash tag

```
 "(\\#\\w+[+]*)(?=[ ,]|$)"
```

with optional single plus sign as part of hash tag

```
 "(\\#\\w+[+]?)(?=[ ,]|$)"
```

Comment: The second option of your solution accounts for #C++, which was something I hadn't thought of until you mentioned it! Thanks so very much and yes, this sorts me out clean! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `(\\#\\w+)` (no space at the end)

This will match **#hashtags**, **#Google** (no plus sign), **#Twitter** and **#Youtube**

If you want to add the `+` sign as a valid hashtag, use this: `\\#[\\w+]+`

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much! Yeah it works perfect, and it was exactly what I wanted. So very many thanks!

@sln below added another dimension to it, which included something like  C++ and its why I am accepting his answer. Wish I could upvote yours but my reputation points are unfortunately low. Once again, thanks a million!!!

Comment: That's okay, glad to help you.